# CentOS7 - "Could not connect: [111] Connection refused"

Tags: php, mysql, server, connection-refused

I've got a PHP/mysql webapp hosted on a remote server running CentOS7. If I try to run a database search on this site, it instantly returns the following error:

`Could not connect: [111] Connection refused`.

I've already ensured that the bind-address and skip-networking options are commented out in the my.conf file. I've also given full grants to `root@localhost` and made sure to open the appropriate ports in the firewall(3306 and 50005).

I can connect using mysql workbench and telnet, so I'm not sure where the problem lies. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you restart the mysql service after commenting in the `.conf` file ?

Comment: I did, yes. I also rebooted the machine just to be sure.

Comment: Does the connection only fail when apache is involved? Perhaps an selinux issue?

Comment: @chris85 I initially thought it might be an selinux issue, but I've gone so far as disabling it completely in a test environment on a different server with the same results.

Comment: After disabling it you did a system restart? I've found the selinux doesnt get disabled until a full restart

Comment: @chris85 I did, yes. I tried both the temporary method (setenforce 0) without reboot and the permanent method (SELinux=disabled) with reboot.